# How to sort sub-documents in the array field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm using the MongoDB shell to fetch some results, ordered. Here's a sampler,

```
{
"_id" : "32022",
"topics" : [
    {
        "weight" : 281.58551703724993,
        "words" : "some words"
    },
    {
        "weight" : 286.6695125796183,
        "words" : "some more words"
    },
    {
        "weight" : 289.8354232846977,
        "words" : "wowz even more wordz"
    },
    {
        "weight" : 305.70093587160807,
        "words" : "WORDZ"
    }]
}
```

what I want to get is, same structure, but ordered by `"topics" : []`

```
{
"_id" : "32022",
"topics" : [
    {
        "weight" : 305.70093587160807,
        "words" : "WORDZ"
    },
    {
        "weight" : 289.8354232846977,
        "words" : "wowz even more wordz"
    },
    {
        "weight" : 286.6695125796183,
        "words" : "some more words"
    },
    {
        "weight" : 281.58551703724993,
        "words" : "some words"
    },
    ]
}
```

I managed to get some ordered results, but no luck in grouping them by id field. is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to show us sample documents with the expected result, not just what you got.

Comment: @user3100115 check updated question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't provide a way to do this out of the box but there is a workaround which is to update your documents and use the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) update operator to sort your array.

```python
db.collection.update_many({}, {"$push": {"topics": {"$each": [], "$sort": {"weight": -1}}}})
```

You can still use the `.aggregate()` method like this:

```python
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$topics"}, 
    {"$sort": {"_id": 1, "topics.weight": -1}}, 
    {"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "topics": {"$push": "$topics"}}}
])
```

But this is less efficient if all you want is sort your array, and you definitely shouldn't do that.

---

You could always do this client side using the [`.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) or [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to update but only get documents, you can use the following query

```
 db.test.aggregate(
 [
   {$unwind : "$topics"},
   {$sort : {"topics.weight":-1}},
   {"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "topics": {"$push": "$topics"}}}
 ]
)
```

Comment: adding `{"$match": {"_id":"12345"}},` for pipeline parameters spits out exactly what I want to get!

Comment: @BediE did you notice that this is a copy of my answer and doesn't add any value to the existing one?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate(
{$project:{topics:1}},
{$unwind:"$topics"},
{$sort :{"topics.words":1}})
```

Comment: This is wrong it will not give the expected result.