# Mongoose - Cannot populate with sort on path notifications.from because it is a subproperty of a document array

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a very simple mongo scheme I'm accessing with mongoose

I can map the username and firstname to each notification's from field by using populate, the issue is I can't seem to get any sorting to work on the date field

With this code I get an error of

> MongooseError: Cannot populate with sort on path notifications.from
>   because it is a subproperty of a document array

Is it possible to do this a different way, or newer way (deep populate, virtuals)? I'm on Mongoose 5.

I'd rather not use vanilla javascript to sort the object afterwards or create a separate schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({  
    username: String,
    firstname: String,
    notifications: [
        {  
            from: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
            date: Date,
            desc: String
        }
    ]
});

app.get('/notifications', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ _id: req._id }, 'notifications')
    .populate({
        path: 'notifications.from',   
        populate: {
            path: 'from',
            model: 'User',
            options: { sort: { 'notifications.date': -1 } }            
        }
    }) 
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
    })
});
```

That possible duplicate is almost 2 years old about Mongo. I'm asking if there are newer or different ways of doing this in Mongoose as it has changed a bit since 2016 with newer features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort sub-documents in the array field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875995/how-to-sort-sub-documents-in-the-array-field)

Comment: That possible duplicate is almost 2 years old about Mongo. I'm asking if there are newer or different ways of doing this in Mongoose -- as it has changed a bit since 2016 with newer features.

Answer (score 3):

From Mongoose V5.0.12 FAQ : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#populate_sort_order

> **Q.** I'm populating a nested property under an array like the below
>   code:
>
> new Schema({
>       arr: [{
>         child: { ref: 'OtherModel', type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }
>       }]   });
>
> .populate({ path: 'arr.child', options: { sort: 'name' } }) won't sort by arr.child.name?
>
> **A.** See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2202). It's a known issue but one that's
>   exceptionally difficult to fix.

So unfortunately, for now, it's not possible,

One way to achieve this is to simply use `javascript`'s native `sort` to sort the notifications after fetching.

```
.exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) console.log(err)

    user.notifications.sort(function(a, b){ 
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    });

})
```

Comment: won't that be an issue when one would lazy load with pagination?

Comment: no, `.sort()` only sorts the result you're getting from the database, it does the same thing that `sort: { 'notifications.date': -1 }` would do ( without `populate` ), it doesn't change the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
It can be achievable using nesting populate like this - 

eg - schema - {donationHistory: {campaignRequestId: [ref ids]}}

await user.populate({
        path: 'donationHistory.campaignRequestId',
        populate: [{
            path: 'campaignRequestId',
            model: 'CampaignRequest',
            options: { sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } },
        }],
        ...deepUserPopulation,
    }).execPopulate();
```