# How to sort nested field in mongodb / mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

Im trying to sort the comments by its date but i cant do it correct.

```
   {
        "_id": "5defc10b8e753623b4ad0adf",
        "title": "bla bla",
        "owner:"idToPopulate",
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "5dfc2185e62103121cfc0f18",
                "reply": "1",
                "replyDate": "2019-12-10T16:00:11.228Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dfc218be62103121cfc0f19",
                "reply": "2",
                "replyDate": "2019-13-10T16:00:11.228Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is the way i tried ( **the result has to be, sort the comments by it last date**)

```
.sort({"comments.replyDate":1})
```

Comment: Why don't you try '1' instead of '-1'? I think `-1` means ascending order (which would be correct for 1 then 2)

Comment: hi @CeliusStingher my mistake (error typing), but it doesnt work that way too

Comment: You have to use aggregation to sort the sub-documents in an array - sort by the sub-document's field. See the answer with the aggregation in this post: [How to sort sub-documents in the array field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875995/how-to-sort-sub-documents-in-the-array-field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) you can sort your data, but before using that you have to split your array. Try with this mongo query:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$comments"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "comments.replyDate": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      comments: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$comments._id",
          item: "$comments.reply",
          date: "$comments.replyDate"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: im sorry, but it doesnt work, i mean, doesnt retrieve the result (even omitting the serverResponse)

Comment: @AlexHunter Updated query as per your edited collection data

Comment: now it works!, one last thing in that object, outside of the comments object array i have more information, how can i show it too?

Comment: Just group that values in $group stage as:  
_id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        example_data: "$example_data"
      } and the add one more stage $project to collect all required values

Comment: i tried that way and it shows, but, it changes the object order, i updated my post with the data, by the way some fields need populate too

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$comments"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "comments.replyDate": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        title: "$title",
        owner: "$owner"
      },
      comments: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$comments._id",
          item: "$comments.reply",
          date: "$comments.replyDate"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      title: "$_id.title",
      owner: "$_id.owner",
      comments: "$comments"
    }
  }
]) try this

Comment: no it doesnt populate, the chat is open, lets go there please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204678/discussion-between-alex-hunter-and-mayuri-s-kulkarni).